# google scripting to email someone when their name is inserted into a cell

Tags: excel, scripting, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, issue-tracking

I am trying to make a ticketing system using google spreadsheets wherein employees or customers can input their inquiries in a form and it gets saved to a spreadsheet that I can view. One of the things I need is to be able to fill out a cell in the row of the inquiry with an employees name and this will assign that employee to this issue to try and fix it. I need to know if theres a way to use google scripts to do this. I know how to do it if you're checking the whole column but I don't want to email everyone every time I add a name to a cell, just that individual person.

For example, a customer fills out the form saying they're having Issue A and once I go into the spreadsheet I see it has been updated and want to assign the issue to a specific person so I fill out the cell in a column I've designated that I can fill out who its assigned to. Once I assign it to a person, they get an email with that row of data so they know the issue.

Hopefully I explained this enough. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick example:

You will have to check the code and adapt it to your particular setup (ie: sheet name, position of data etc...).

Hope this help.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  doEvent(e);
}

function doEvent(e) {

  var ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet     = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();
  var r         = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var col       = r.getColumn() ;
  var row       = r.getRow();

  var i = 0 ;

  switch ( sheetName ) {
    case 'MySheet' : // just to make sure you are on the right sheet
      if ( row > 1 ) { // skip headers row if you have
        var ticketDataRange = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, numberOfColumnsToGrab);
        var ticketData = ticketDataRange.getValues();
        if ( col == columnEmailOfOwnerOfTicket ) {
          var emailOwnerOfTicket = ticketData[columnEmailOfOwnerOfTicker-1];
          GmailApp.sendEmail( emailOwnerOfTicket, "New Task Assigned", '', {htmlBody: 'A new task has been assigned to you by: <strong>Me!</strong><br>Task Linked to Contact: <strong>BlahBlah</strong><br><br>Here can be description' + ticketData[positionOfDescription].replace(/\n/g, '<br>') + '<br><br><p>Due Date: <strong>' + Utilities.formatDate(ticketData[positionOfDueDate],SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(),"EEE, MMM d, yyyy") + '</strong></p><br>' } );
        }
      }
      break;
  }

}
```